# variable in bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

Can someone explain why we require $ Sign in 3rd Command. 
Why without dollar it is not working

```
[kony@HOSTNAME test]$ var1=1

[kony@HOSTNAME test]$ var1=[ var1 + 1 ]
bash: var1: command not found...
[kony@HOSTNAME test]$ var1=$[ var1 + 1 ]
[kony@HOSTNAME test]$ echo $var1
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var1=[ var1 + 1 ]` is like `var1=[ env` or `LC_ALL=C date`. There are two parts: `var1=[` is an assignment and `var1 + 1 ]` is a command with arguments. If `var1` could be run, it would be run with `var1` in its environment; the value of the variable would be `[`.

But there is no `var1` command, hence the error.

Note `]` does not require any opening `[`. These are not special at all. If you ever see a command like `[ "$foo" -eq 1 ]` then remember it's just a command named `[` whose arguments are: the expanded value of `$foo`, `-eq`, `1` *and* `]` (this does not apply to `[[ "$foo" -eq 1 ]]` though).

If the line is `var1=[ var1 + 1 ]` then there is *no connection whatsoever* between `[` and `]` in it.

To see what `var1=[` does in such case, run the following code:

```
var1=1
var1=[ sh -c 'echo "$var1"'
echo "$var1"
```

You will see `[` and `1`. Thanks to `var1=[` preceding `sh -c …` the new shell was run with `var1` already in its environment, the value was `[`. When asked, the shell expanded its variable to `[`. The value of `var1` in the main shell was not affected by this. If `var1=[` was a separate command (like `var1=1` earlier), it would affect the variable in the main shell.

---

`var1=$[ var1 + 1 ]` is different. It uses a [deprecated form of arithmetic expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209846/108618). Nowadays instead of `$[…]` we should use `$((…))`. When you invoke `var1=$[ var1 + 1 ]`, the expansion occurs first and the result is assigned to the variable.

For convenience the shell doesn't require variable names within `$(( ))` (or `$[ ]`) to be prefixed with `$`. Almost anything that doesn't look like an integer or operator is assumed to be a variable name. Still using `$var1` would also work:

```
var1=$((var1+1))
# or
var1=$(($var1+1))
# if you run both then the variable value will increase by two
```